# Linux displaying issue

Tags: graphics

I am having trouble installing Linux on my computer; I have tried many distros, and they all had problems, previously I had windows 7 and had no problems. The computer has processor(AMDAthlon iix3455 processor x3) Graphics(NV4C) and 3gb ram
when opening apps it's a lot worse:

[image: Desktop screenshot]

Comment: Hey user1365885! What are the distros that you have tried?

Comment: pop os, and I also tried lubuntu, in which i couldn't even boot into, whereas pop os had the same problem

Comment: Since your processor is an old model, I suggest you to try light-weight Linux distros. This article might be helpful: https://itsfoss.com/lightweight-linux-beginners/

Comment: This looks like GPU artifacting. That's a hardware problem. Because the problem manifests on multiple operating systems, this could confirm that it's a hardware problem